# In Titanium how do I execute a button click event from code?

Tags: iphone, android, titanium

I tried

```
btn.click();
```

And the error message is 'Cannot call property click in object ti.modules.titanium.ui.ButtonProxy@44f61.  It is not a function, it is "object"'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
btn.fireEvent('click');
```

this should work

Comment: Yes, that's right. We call fireEvent instead of listening eventListener.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.addEventListener('click',function() {
    Titanium.API.info('Button Clicked');

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have the event listener wired up as you did, and it fires when I click the button.  I want to execute the event handler from code.